# How to do smooth scrolling in UIScrollView?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, performance, xcode, uiscrollview

I am using Apple's [page control sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html) and showing three different types of views.

The scrolling is very slow on the device because I am using a UITableView and 5-7 labels on my view. Everything is updating from a database. How do I increase the performance of my scrolling behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fast Scrolling in Tweetie with UITableView](http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/)

Answer (score 0):

Or you could make sure all components on your UITableViewCells are opaque. UITableView doesn't handle well transparency when scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

As Nick noted, the link back to the original Tweetie article, but I found it in the Wayback Machine - [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20090211181441/http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/)

In researching this issue for myself, I found two other articles that were useful:

[Glassy Scrolling with UITableView](http://www.fieryrobot.com/blog/2008/10/01/glassy-scrolling-with-uitableview/)

[Fun Shadow Effects Using Custom CALayer Shadowpaths](http://nachbaur.com/blog/fun-shadow-effects-using-custom-calayer-shadowpaths) (this is actually what solved my problem - I was using drop shadows in my views)